# Thread.sleep() in a AsyncTask sleep other background threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, sleep

I am listening to notifications using Notification Listener service to listen to google navigation notifications. On removal of notification of i want to wait for n seconds and then perform some task. To achieve this I have made a AsyncTask in service, in which i have used Thread.sleep to sleep the background thread for n seconds and then perform some task.

But this sleep is affecting my other background threads which are running from a foreground service, all these background threads also get delayed due to the above mentioned async task.

I have also tried to use Handler.postDelayed method in notification listener service to perform the task after n second but it never runs.

Please suggest any better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep()` will pause all other `AsyncTasks` running on the same *default* thread pool, not `Threads`.

In Android by default all `AsyncTasks` are executed on one default `ThreadPool`, which has 1 `Thread`. This way they are executed 1 by 1 in background.

So you can define a custom, or a pre-defined `Executor`, on which you want the AsyncTask to be executed:

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly executing AsyncTask from notification removed function callback. So a good option is Handler.postDelayed()

define the handler and runnable in your service class of Notification listener.

```
class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    ...
    class PerformTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      ...
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        PerformTask object = new PerformTask();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            object.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        else
            object.execute();
    };
    ...
}
```

and execute below with delay after required time frame from notification removed section

```
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    ...
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

sleep thread (Asynctask) will pause all otherAsync if running on the same thread pool.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html